# Scala/Play: Write Enumeratee that prepends a value to the stream

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, enumerator, loops

I want to write an enumeratee that just pushes one Input.El into the iteratee and then returns the remaining iteratee. I call it prepend, because it changes the stream by just prepending a value to it.
Here is my try:

```
object Enumeratees {
  def prepend[T](toPrepend: T) = new Enumeratee[T, T] {
    def applyOn[A](inner: Iteratee[T, A]): Iteratee[T, Iteratee[T, A]] = {
      val prepended = Iteratee.flatten(inner.feed(Input.El(toPrepend)))
      Done(prepended, Input.Empty)
    }
  }
}
```

When I now call it via

```
Enumerator(1,2,3,4) |>> (Enumeratees.prepend(0)  &>> Iteratee.foreach[Int]{i=>println(i)})
```

it only prints the 0 which should be prepended. The other values from the enumerator are ignored. If I do also override the &> method of the enumeratee (transform method), I can get it working:

```
def prepend[T](toPrepend: T) = new Enumeratee[T, T] {
  def applyOn[A](inner: Iteratee[T, A]): Iteratee[T, Iteratee[T, A]] = {
    val prepended = Iteratee.flatten(inner.feed(Input.El(toPrepend)))
    Done(prepended, Input.Empty)
  }

  override def transform[A](inner: Iteratee[T,A]): Iteratee[T,A] =
    Iteratee.flatten(inner.feed(Input.El(toPrepend)))
}
```

But that's not a very clean way, because the applyOn method still is invalid.
I think I mistakted the meaning of the applyOn method. In my opinion it should return an iteratee that returns the original iteratee and input is continued on the original iteratee then.

The transform method above should explain, what behaviour I want from my enumeratee. How can I achieve this behaviour by overwriting applyOn instead of transform?

Comment: Are you sure you are using &> and not &>> in you sample? transform is only called when &>> is used.

Comment: you're right. I tried both versions and both didn't work, but &>> should be correct. I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either you edit your prepend Enumeratee to be like the following:

```
object Enumeratees {
  def prepend[T](toPrepend: T) = new Enumeratee[T, T] {
    def applyOn[A](inner: Iteratee[T, A]): Iteratee[T, Iteratee[T, A]] = {
      val prepended = Iteratee.flatten(inner.feed(Input.El(toPrepend)))
      Enumeratee.passAlong[T](prepended)
    }
  }
}
```

Or you get the original Iteratee after applying the Enumeratee and the Enumerator to it, something like [Scala: Getting original iteratee after applying enumeratee (example from play documentation doesn't compile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968637/scala-getting-original-iteratee-after-applying-enumeratee-example-from-play-do/10968790#comment14322714_10968790)

`&>>` will end the inside iteratee when the outside is Done. This is the only way to be able to get `Iteratee[EOuter,AInner]` since Enumeratee are mostly about adapting.

Comment: The passAlong approach works. Thank you. Is there some documentation or explanation what passAlong does? I found nothing about it in the play ScalaDocs.

Comment: It is an Enumeratee that does nothing but passing along input to the inner iteratee. You are right it is not documented (It was under Traversable).

Comment: It's worth noting that `Enumeratee.heading` and `Enumeratee.trailing` were implemented [shortly after this answer](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/commit/209a2d69d79698167b793e2df913ed68df2a5530) (thanks @Sadache) so there is no longer any need to define a custom `prepend` Enumeratee.

Comment: Dylan, thanks for saving me an enormous amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
Enumerator(1,2,3,4) |>>
Iteratee.flatten( Enumerator(0) |>> Iteratee.foreach[Int]{i=>println(i)} )
```

or

```
Enumerator(1,2,3,4) |>> (Enumeratees.prepend2(0) &> Iteratee.foreach[Int]{i=>println(i)})
```

Comment: The first approach doesn't work, because I need the enumeratee object. This enumeratee will be combined with other enumeratees, before it's applied to different streams. Your second approach is the same as mine above which didn't work.